# operator overloading + for string concatenation

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading

I am facing issue '+' operator overloading for string concatenation.
here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <new>

 using namespace std;

class kinda
{
int a;


    public: 
        char *name;
    kinda()
    {
        //cout<<"in base class constr"<<endl;
        a=100;
        name=new char[strlen("sumnesumne")+1];  
        strcpy(name,"sumne");
        //name="sumne";
    }

    ~kinda()
    {
        //cout<<"in base class destr"<<endl;
        delete name;
    }

    kinda(int val,char *naam)
    {
        //cout<<"in base class param constr"<<endl;
        a=val;
        name= new (char) (strlen(naam)+1);
        strcpy(name,naam);
    }

    kinda(kinda &obj)
    {
        //cout<<"in base class copy constr"<<endl;
        a=obj.a;
        name= new (char) (strlen(obj.name)+1);
        strcpy(name,obj.name);
    }

    void display()
    {
        //cout<<"in base class display()"<<endl;
        cout<<"a="<<a<<endl;
        cout<<"name="<<name<<endl<<endl;
    }
};


class kinda2 : public kinda
{

int ab;
public :

kinda2()
{
    //cout<<"in der class default constr"<<endl;
    ab=100;
}

kinda2(int val)
{
    //cout<<"in der class param constr"<<endl;
    ab=val;
}
void dis()
{
    //cout<<"in der class display()"<<endl;
    cout<<"ab : "<<ab <<endl;
    display();
}

kinda2 operator+(const kinda2& ob)
{
    kinda2 retobj;
    //cout<<"in der class op overloading"<<endl;

    retobj.ab= ab + ob.ab;
    cout<<" before : "<< retobj.name<<endl;
    strcpy(retobj.name,name);
    cout<<"middle : "<< retobj.name<<endl;
    strcat(retobj.name,ob.name);
    cout<<"after : "<<retobj.name<<endl;
    return retobj;


}

};

int main()
{
    kinda ob(7,"pachka"),ob1(ob);
    kinda2 ob2,ob3,ob4;

/*  cout<<"ob details:"<<endl;
ob.display();

//ob1(ob);
cout<<"ob1 details:"<<endl;
ob1.display();
*/
    cout<<"ob2 details:"<<endl;
ob2.dis();
cout<<"ob2 details:"<<endl;
ob3.dis();

ob4=ob2+ob3;

ob4.dis();
return 0;
}
```

the code involves simple inheritance as well.

with '+' operator overloading i am trying to concatenate the 'name' variable.
the output i am getting is this:

```
ob2 details:
ab : 100
a=100
name=sumne

ob2 details:
ab : 100
a=100
name=sumne

 before : sumne
middle : sumne
after : sumnesumne
ab : 200
a=100
name=X☺2


--------------------------------
Process exited with return value 3221226356
Press any key to continue . . .
```

within the operator overloading function, it shows the correct value.
But with display() i am seeing some unexpected values.

Comment: [Rule of 3/5/0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)).

Comment: The expression `name= new (char) (strlen(obj.name)+1);` does not do what you expect it to. Is there a reason you don't use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)?

Comment: no specific reason... i was just trying the basic coding..

Comment: The copy constructor `kinda(kinda &obj)` should take a `const kinda& obj`.  And `new (char) (strlen(naam)+1);` is wrong as Joachim said... use `[]`s around the length.

Comment: yeah... tried modifying above said changes.... but still the output is same..!!